# JupyterHub Redirecting to /user/tree not working

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub

- Step 1: Spawning a user pod is successful via JWT token.
- Step 2: Hub should redirect to {{url}}/jhub/user/john.doe12/tree but its throwing Bad Gateway 502 error
- Step 3: Now if try and hit {{url}}/jhub/user/john.doe12/tree seperately it works.

[image: Single user pod logs]

Comment: Does `{{url}}/user/john.doe12/tree` (without the jhub) work?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado No, it does not. Also I want to mention the token I am using for authentication is a JWT which has a length of 1000+ chars.

Comment: can you paste the logs into the question as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting)? generally, [posting code/logs/data/errors as images is discouraged](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as they're not searchable, indexible, parseable by screen readers and assistive devices, etc.

Comment: when you do - make sure to include the 502 error - I don't see it in the logs.

Comment: Actually the page {{url}}/user/john.doe12/tree opened without JHUB. The problem was with redirecting, and I resolved it by reducing the length of the TOKEN. Apparently, there's some restriction on the length/format of the URL. I didn't find any solid reason behind it, but yes shortening the token length worked smoothly.